# Installing handlebars without npm

Tags: npm, handlebars.js

I want to install handlebars. As I am behind company firewall, I am not able to install handlebars.

I tried setting npm proxy settings too.

But I get following error

```
npm ERR! Error: shasum check failed for 
npm ERR! Expected: 0e09651a2f0fb3c949160583710d551f92e6d2ad
npm ERR! Actual:   887b52cd1c51b8406f4e825a77b489b75458504c
npm ERR! From:     http://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars/-/handlebars-3.0.3.tgz
npm ERR!     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\sha\index.
js:38:8
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm
\node_modules\sha\index.js:85:7)
npm ERR!     at ReadStream.emit (events.js:117:20)
npm ERR!     at _stream_readable.js:943:16
npm ERR!     at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

So can the handlebars be installed without using npm ?

Comment: download it? http://handlebarsjs.com/

Comment: Ya I get a js file. I can compile the templates in browser. But I need to install handlebars to precompile the templates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
npm config set proxy http://login:pass@host:port
npm config set https-proxy http://login:pass@host:port
```

or

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

If you still get an error, you might need to change the execution policy in Powershell with:

```
set-executionpolicy unrestricted -s cu
```

You may also be able to utilize package managers specific to Windows like [Scoop](http://scoop.sh) or [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/).